# Constructed stylesheet replaceSync method not parsing all text

Tags: javascript, css

I'm creating a constructed stylesheet using `new CSSStyleSheet()`. However, when I call `.replaceSync()` on it I notice it is not creating all the rules.

For example, if I create

```js
const sh = new CSSStyleSheet();
sh.replaceSync('.css-o1r3d5::before { font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro"; content: "\f00c"; color: transparent; }');
```

I get a stylesheet with 1 rule in it. However, if I do

```js
const sh = new CSSStyleSheet();
sh.replaceSync('.css-o1r3d5::before { font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro"; content: "\f00c"; color: transparent; } .css-o1r3d5:focus { border-color: rgb(14, 106, 237); box-shadow: rgb(14, 106, 237) 0px 0px 4px 0px; }');
```

In this case I *still* only have one rule. For some reason the rule `.css-o1r3d5:focus` is entirely omitted.

What's weird though is if I call `replaceSync` with those two rules a bit more formatted (just adding line breaks) I get

```js
const sh = new CSSStyleSheet();

sh.replaceSync(`.css-o1r3d5::before {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro"; 
    content: "\f00c"; 
    color: transparent; 
}

.css-o1r3d5:focus { 
    border-color: rgb(14, 106, 237); 
    box-shadow: rgb(14, 106, 237) 0px 0px 4px 0px; 
}`);
```

and the stylesheet has *both* rules. What is the difference between the flat string and the formatted one? Why is one rule getting shaved off in the flat case but not the formatted one?

Comment: Are you using React?

Comment: No this is all vanilla JS.

Comment: I haven't tested the outcome, but it looks like both will be added if you escape the \ in content so it will be: **content: "\\f00c"**